# Why does Typescript complain that an object is not assignable to its type?

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, types

When running the following TypeScript code:

```
type valueType = {[key: string]: number} | {[key: string]: {[date: string]: number}} | {[key: string]: string;}


const myData1: valueType = {
  "name": "Eduardo",
  "city": "Miami",
  "state": "FL",
  "age": 22,
  "progress": {"2018": 67, "2019": 76, "2020": 89}
}
```

TypeScript complains that the object is not assignable to the type `valueType` although I explicitly tell it can have different types inside the object. What would be the proper way of allowing multiple different types inside an object?

This is the warning I get:

```
Type '{ "name": string; "city": string; "state": string; "age": number; }' is not assignable to type 'valueType'.
  Type '{ "name": string; "city": string; "state": string; "age": number; }' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: string; }'.
    Property '"age"' is incompatible with index signature.
      Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{ [key: string]: number }
```

This type says that all properties must be a number.

```
{ [key: string]: { [date: string]: number } }
```

This type says that all properties must be an object, all of whose properties are numbers.

```
{ [key: string]: string; }
```

This type says that all properties must be a string.

```
type valueType =
    | { [key: string]: number }
    | { [key: string]: { [date: string]: number } }
    | { [key: string]: string; }
```

This type says that it is one of the three above possibilities. Meaning it must be all numbers, all string, or all objects.

It does not allow you to mix and match these.

So I think you have the union in the wrong place. You want one object type, but the *properties* could be any of the three possibilities.

```
type ValueType = {
  [key: string]: number | string | { [date: string]: number }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=4.0.0-beta#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK4QCrmgXigbwFBRQDaA1hCAFxQDOwATgJYB2A5gLpVNIC2ARhHSgAfGvWYthuYgBM4wCFVqNWHKFz4CoAXzxaoePAGMA9k1pRuIACJy4ARirxkaDFGz5CAIiZxuET1SeAKLSSHB00saeADQEUJ6GDKAB8QCyDL4MMXGetHL+gQBiADLZXnAsBVAATNWxXmB0xix0ENTUKTie1QAMdgAcKQBsAOzR8b12AJwpI0Pj3T29Kf1TOjp4QA)

---

But if you wanted to type this particular bit of data more strictly, you can do that in one simple interface:

```
interface ValueType {
  name: string
  city: string
  state: string
  age: number
  progress: { [date: string]: number }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=4.0.0-beta&ssl=3&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGpwDYFcIBUCeADigN4BQyyIcAthAFzIDOYUoA5hcgsGPoyzYhOlFnEgDWHLnHYMqWGgCNoXQlAD27KBCZNGJZAG0AJuPmCOAXUYhFKqMgC+ZF2QQaQLZDXwARcTgARkZ0bDwiFABeZHJKACJqOnjGeIBREyw4KBMNeIAaLniePhTkeIBZYFpgAqKxSDL4gDEAGTqE2QgygCYewoT1LR09MpJ4noAGIIAOMoA2AHZ88qmggE4yxfmVicmpspn1lzcgA)

Comment: Wow! Thank you. If I replace "key" with "age" will that force the key to always be "age"?

Comment: Not exactly. But if you want to strictly type this particular object, you can use a simple interface with no unions at all. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the `valueType` type in your code is that you're telling typescript that the type will have key-value pairs where the keys are strings and all values are either numbers or strings or of the type `{[date: string]: number}}`. But what you need is a type that has `string` keys and `number`/`string` values in the same object.

Try this:

```
type valueType = {[key: string]: number | string | { [date: string]: number }};

const myData1: valueType = {
  "name": "Eduardo",
  "city": "Miami",
  "state": "FL",
  "age": 22,
  "progress": {"2018": 67, "2019": 76, "2020": 89}
}
```

If you want your type to have fixed keys:

```
type valueType = { name: string, city: string, state: string, age: number, progress: { [date: string]: number } };
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked! How would you explicitly tell it that you only accept keys  "name", "city", "state", "age", "progress"?

Comment: @EduardoMorales instead of `[key: string]` use `name` etc.

Comment: @EduardoMorales Updated my answer.